# In CSS i tried to overwrite important but failed

Tags: css

I tried to overwrite p-3 with p-0 but failed.

```
<div class= "card p-3 p-0">
```

```css
.p-0{ padding: 0rem !important; }
.p-3{ padding: 0.75rem !important; }
```

[image: failed like this]

Shouldn't it be overwritten with the class in the back?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order?

Comment: @MSC What you showed is the right cascade. What exactly did you expect?

Comment: You will need to add more details if you want help like why do you want to overwrite? From your example removing p-3 from the element would solve the issue. But if it's a responsive issue and you want to change the padding based on the viewport size, then there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, the last rule takes precedence over any previous, conflicting, rules. So, `.p-3` is being applied and not `.p-0`. Swap them and it should work.

As a side note, overuse of `!important` is generally considered bad-practice as it can confuse things as the stylesheet grows.

Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct `.p-3` will override `.p-0` since both properties are same and `.p-3` is lowest meaning nearer to the element... In the cascading order.

Comment: Thanks Felix for that..but later when I saw the Daniel_Knights answer then I thought I should have explained about !important as well :)

Comment: Yea, I feel the same too... It's alright... Made your answer a bit okay! 